# Php using a function to add on a number to a outside variable

Tags: php, function, variables, global

```
<form method="post">
    <select name="racebox">
        <option>select</option>
        <option>human</option>
    </select>
    <input type="textbox" name="ability" value= "">
    <input type="textbox" name="strength" value= "">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
<?php
$ability=$_POST['ability'];
$strength=$_POST['strength'];
$racepick=$_POST['racebox'];

function race($racepick){
    if ($racepick === "human"):
        $strength +1;
    endif;

}

function modifier($num){
$modifier= floor($num/2-5);
if ($modifier >= 0):
    echo " ", "+","$modifier <br>";
elseif ($modifier < 0):
    echo " ", $modifier, "<br>";
endif;
}

modifier($ability);
modifier($strength);

?>
```

Trying to make a dnd character sheet, I want to be able to pick human and have it add a set amount to the variables gotten from 'strength' these will be predetermined prior and be different to every selection box option.

Comment: `type="textbox"` that isn't a valid type; `text` is

Comment: The `modifier` function doesn't return a value and only echos the value back on screen so you'll not be able to use the value anywhere else.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thank you Fred, I fixed that problem.

Comment: @RamRaider Thanks for the help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Upon review, what you should do is pass `$strength` to your `race()` function and return it with the amount of strength added to it.

```
$ability = $_POST['ability'];
$strength = $_POST['strength'];
$racepick = $_POST['racebox'];

$strength = race($racepick, $strength) {
    switch ($racepick) {
        case 'human':
            $strength = $strenght + 1;
            break;
        case 'otherrace':
            $strength = $strength + 5;
            break;
    }
    return $strength;
}
```

#### Additional information

Functions are generally used so that programmers can re use certain parts of code. It is only usefull to use functions if you are not planning on using this code again in some other script I would like to suggest dropping the function all together and just doing the following:

```
$ability = $_POST['ability'];
$strength = $_POST['strength'];
$racepick = $_POST['racebox'];


switch ($racepick) {
    case 'human':
        $strength = $strenght + 1;
        break;
    case 'otherrace':
        $strength = $strength + 5;
        break;
}
```

Comment: I'll give this a go @Peter

Comment: Note: This answer failed to outline the type and it should be included in the answer. Another thing, his code will output undefined index notices, given he's using both the form and php inside the same file. This is just a note for future visitors.